# Storing NSDate in SQLite retrieving and displaying shows in GMT, need to display time in original timezone it was created in

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When user creates a new record, I store the `NSDate` in SQLite with local timezone (say PST). When the same `NSDate` is retrieved from DB, the time is treated as GMT (which is understandable, since `NSDate` has no concept of timezone and is absolute).

I want to display the `NSDate` with the time as per the timezone it was created in - For example, if `NSDate` is stored in a PST timezone and later, user moves to Northeast US, I still want to be able to retrieve the `NSDate` from DB and display the time in PST (and not EDT). Should I store the local timezone when the record is created, so that that timezone is used in displaying the time?

This is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
NSDate *date = xxxxxxxxxxx; // This is retrieved from DB
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
NSString *timeStr = [format stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Time :%@",timeStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> Should I store the local time zone when the record is created, so that that timezone is used in displaying the time?

Yes, that's one approach: Save the timezone information in a separate field in the database. So, when saving the date, in addition to writing the date in GMT in the database, in a separate field, save the name of the current time zone:

```
NSString *timeZoneName = [NSCalendar currentCalendar].timeZone.name;
```

(Note, I'm not using the `abbreviation`, because those are not unique.)

And then, after retrieving the date and the time zone name from the database, use `NSDateFormatter` to output the date in the correct format:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneName];
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

By the way, notice that I used `a` (the AM/PM) designator in my format string (since you didn't use `HH` for hour).

Frankly, if you wanted to be friendly for international users, I would avoid `dateFormat` and use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` instead:

```
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked! Appreciate the quick response